# XSLT to support backward compatibility

Tags: xml, xslt

You have got xml something like this:

```html
 <q:foo
      xmlns:q="http://www.example.com/foo-1_0" xmlns:p="http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_0"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/foo/foo-1_0.xsd">
      <p:payload>
        <p:var-list>
          <p:var>
            <p:key>key1</p:key>
            <p:value xsi:type="xs:string">string content</p:value>
          </p:var>
        </p:var-list>
      </p:payload>
    </q:foo>
```

However, the person who wrote it didn't know that the true identifier of the namespace of the document is not http://www.example.com/foo-**1_0**, but rather http://www.example.com/foo-**1_1**. So you need a style sheet to update the url. Here comes the xslt to that.

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:old="http://www.example.com/foo-1_0"
  xmlns:q="http://www.example.com/foo-1_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:oldc="http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_0" xmlns:p="http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_1">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:namespace name="xs" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation">
    <xsl:attribute name="xsi:{'schemaLocation'}">
          <xsl:value-of select="'http://www.example.com/foo/foo-1_1.xsd'"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="old:*">
    <xsl:element name="q:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="oldc:*">
    <xsl:element name="p:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and output is as expected.

```html
<q:foo xmlns:q="http://www.example.com/foo-1_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/foo/foo-1_1.xsd">
  <p:payload xmlns:p="http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_1">
    <p:var-list>
      <p:var>
        <p:key>key1</p:key>
        <p:value xsi:type="xs:string">string content</p:value>
      </p:var>
    </p:var-list>
  </p:payload>
</q:foo>
```

When I am trying to validate the output xml, **xsi:type="xs:string"** not getting resolved due to its not generated in output xml. Any one please help me out how to include the following to *foo* element of output xml?

```xml
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using XSLT 2.0 and already know about `<xsl:namespace name="xs" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />` you can simply put it in the template where you map the `old:*` to new elements, as the root element is one of those it will then have the namespace declaration:

`<xsl:template match="old:*"> 
  <xsl:element name="q:{local-name()}"> 
    <xsl:namespace name="xs" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" /> 
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xsl:copy-of` to copy the in-scope namespaces on an element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:old="http://www.example.com/foo-1_0"
                xmlns:q="http://www.example.com/foo-1_1" 
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:oldc="http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_0" 
                xmlns:p="http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_1">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="CopyNamespaces">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[. != 'http://www.example.com/foo-1_0' and 
                                      . != 'http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_0']"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@xsi:schemaLocation">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
      <xsl:text>http://www.example.com/foo/foo-1_1.xsd</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="old:*">
    <xsl:element name="q:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:call-template name="CopyNamespaces" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="oldc:*">
    <xsl:element name="p:{local-name()}">
      <xsl:call-template name="CopyNamespaces" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here's an extra fancy version of that `CopyNamespaces` template that also copies namespaces from the XSLT itself, so that you can have the `p` namespace declaration on the result document root element instead of below it:

```
<xsl:template name="CopyNamespaces">
  <xsl:copy-of select="(. | document('')/*)/namespace::*
                              [. != 'http://www.example.com/foo-1_0' and 
                               . != 'http://www.example.com/common/goo-1_0' and 
                               . != 'http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform']"/>
</xsl:template>
```